# Summing two lists NOT element wise in python without using for loop

Tags: python, list, function, sum

I am trying to add two lists without using a for loop (inbuilt function? , generators?)

For example let us use the following lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,15,19]
```

I want the following result:

```
c = [11,12,13,16,17,18,20,21,22]
```

How can I accomplish this?
Please keep in mind that using a loop structure will give the result I am looking for but since I am working with pretty big lists, I want a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: Why is a loop not 'smart'?  List comprehensions, generators, etc, still wind up doing the same amount of work.  Is the goal to produce the result lazily?

Comment: Is your intention to generate / use a small amount of the final list instead of the entire list?

Comment: You can rig up something using itertools but it's still a loop. There's no way around that. Also, do it using lists and then measure whether this addition is your bottleneck. If so, you can worry about optimising there. Otherwise, I think this is not a worthwhile consideration.

Comment: What the hell is wrong with a loop? It's essential to do nearly everything when you're dealing with lists.

Comment: "since I am working with pretty big lists, I want a smarter way of doing this" - if by "smarter", you mean "faster", no dice. You can try to microoptimize, but you'll still need to add all pairs of numbers, and you're not going to avoid that by avoiding an explicit loop.

Comment: You could use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop...

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,15,19]
[x+y for x,y in itertools.product(b,a)]
#>> [11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22]
```

Comment: `for` is a loop. The OP asked for an answer that doesn't use loops (or at least not explicitly).

Comment: @alfasin This is impossible without the use of loops... and this is a LC

Comment: @KDawG you should post this comment as an answer :)

Comment: The use of `for` in generators/list comprehensions is different from its use in loops; if `map` isn't a loop, neither is this.  Ultimately it results in looping code, of course...

Comment: Perhaps a more compact version is `map(sum, itertools.product([1,2,3],[10,15,19]))`, but this would only work in Python 2.x, in 3.x `map` produces a generator.

Comment: @KDawG Everything is possible without loops.

Comment: @Hyperboreus that's only true under fairly restrictive definitions of 'loop'.  Recursion is a looping construct.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a for loop, but it's compact:

```
[i + j for i in b for j in a ]
```

Comment: As I said above, I don't think a list comprehension counts as a for loop.  Not that I understand OP's objection to explicit loops in the first place...

Comment: @MarkReed Yeah, I'm under the impression that list comprehension, map, etc. are more efficient that an "explicit" python for loop.

Comment: True, probably because they can build the result more efficiently than user code which explicitly initializes and appends to a list. According to cProfile on my 2.7 install, your solution is about 45% faster than my `itertools.product`-based one, which is still twice as fast as a simple nested for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `numpy` is available:

```
import numpy as np
print (np.array(a)+np.array(b)[:,None]).flatten().tolist()
# [11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22]
```

This still uses iteration, but it is buried in the numpy C code.

This calculates an outer sum, and then flattens it and turns it back into a list

```
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 18],
       [20, 21, 22]])
```